# Is there any build-in way to take advantage of "tomcat-users.xml" from external server?

Tags: spring, security, tomcat, authentication

I am trying to find out if there is any build-in option on Tomcat to use it's authentication credentials from remote server?

We build some application based on Spring Boot and that application should use authentication based on the credentials configured on another Tomcat server. Ideally I think about some kind of Web Service for the authentication which Tomcat may provide, but as far as I remember there is nothing like that available. Any thoughts on that?

Please don't advise LDAP or dedicated solutions - I can't use them on that particular case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The components in Tomcat that authenticate users are called `Realm`, and there's quite a lot of them already implemented. You can find an overview of them, what they do and how to configure them on the [Realm documentation page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/realm.html).

Check if any of the other existing ones (some access a database, which might qualify as an external server in your usecase - you judge that for yourself) will suit your needs.

You can even find a realm for LDAP in there if that will ever become an option ;)